# ms project 2010 roll up task, milestones hidden behind tasks

Tags: tasks, microsoft-project-2010

I am trying to use roll up tasks in project, however my milestones are being hidden behind the tasks, is it possible to force the milestone tasks to the front view?

Answer (score 0):

Subordinate milestones are always rolled up into the parent task when rollup is used.

Perhaps a better way of representing what you need might be to use the Timeline functionality. Go to the View menu and check the Timeline box. Then you can mark individual tasks and milestones to be represented in the Timeline at your discretion. These are not affected by rollups.

Another common method, if you don't use Timeline, would be to create key milestones at the top level and link them to the lower level milestones. Since these are not subordinate they would never be rolled up. I use these a lot to represent things like "Development Start", "Development End", "Testing Start" etc. etc., in conjunction with adding the task dates to the Milestone bar style, so that a rolled up plan clearly shows the major milestones- I often embed that within high level project progress reports.

Answer (score 0):

Bar Styles in the Gantt Chart area are drawn in the same order as they are defined in the Bar Styles window. To show the milestones in front of the Rolled Up task bars just put the definition of the milestone bar styles at the end of the list.

Now, the milestones will be shown in front of the bar.